# $\mathbb{Z}[T]$-Solidification in light condensed setting

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, condensed-mathematics

In the lectures to "Analytic Stacks" Scholze and Clausen introduced a new concept of "light" condensed mathematics. In Lecture 7 Clausen introduces the derived $T$-solidification and claims, that $\underline{R\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathbb{Z}[T]}\left(\mathbb{Z}((T^{-1}))/\mathbb{Z}[T][-1], M\right)$ is our candidate. I get, that \begin{align*}
&\underline{R\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathbb{Z}[T]}\left(\mathbb{Z}((T^{-1}))/\mathbb{Z}[T][-1], \underline{R\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathbb{Z}[T]}(\mathbb{Z}((T^{-1}))/\mathbb{Z}[T][-1], M)\right)=\\
&\underline{R\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathbb{Z}[T]}\left(\mathbb{Z}((T^{-1}))/\mathbb{Z}[T][-1]\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[T]}\mathbb{Z}((T^{-1}))/\mathbb{Z}[T][-1], M\right)=\\
& \underline{R\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathbb{Z}[T]}\left(\mathbb{Z}((T^{-1}))/\mathbb{Z}[T][-1], M\right)
\end{align*}
Now in the proof, that modules of this form are solid I got a little confused. Clausen claims, that we can show by some idempotency, that we can show, that $\underline{R\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathbb{Z}[T]}\left(\mathbb(Z)((T^{-1})),\underline{R\mathrm{Hom}}_{\mathbb{Z}[T]}(\mathbb{Z}((T^{-1}))/\mathbb{Z}[T][-1], M)\right)=0$ by some similar argument, that I couldn't properly work out. I found a paper that addresses a similar problem in the "old" setting (Proposition 3.13): https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.12591, but I wonder, whether there is a nice proof that doesn't require to use extremally disconnected sets but rather uses the methods introduced in this lecture series.

Reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUjn2rGw9SA&t=632s , time: 28:40.

Comment: Andreychev's argument does not really use extremally disconnected sets. He is simply using the fact that $\{\prod_J\mathbb Z\,\vert\,\text{sets $J$}\}$ generates $\mathcal D(\mathbb Z_\blacksquare)$ under colimits and shifts. The light setting is different from the old setting for condensed abelian groups on compact projective objects, but for solid abelian groups (or categories tensored over solid abelian groups), there is no such different.

Comment: The idempotent algebra machinery (aka. symmetric monoidal recollement) is well explained in [Complex.pdf](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/scholze/Complex.pdf), e.g. the first displayed formula on page 50.